# .NET CORE Blazor Server Fonts Not Loading On Mobile

Tags: c#, .net-core, fonts, bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side

i would like to know if somebody has the same issue as i have.
I have developed a website in .NET CORE BLAZOR SERVER that uses BOOTSTRAP.

The problem i have is that on mobile browser's sometimes the font's are not showed.
I'm using custom fonts (not browsers default).

Here is how i'm loading the fonts in the scss file.

```
//Doya Fonts///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$font-display: swap;

//Campton
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Campton Bold';
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Campton Bold'), url('../fonts/campton/CamptonBold.woff') format('woff');
    font-display: $font-display; /* Read next point */
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF; /* Download only latin glyphs */
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Campton Medium';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Campton Medium'), url('../fonts/campton/CamptonMedium.woff') format('woff');
    font-display: $font-display; /* Read next point */
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF; /* Download only latin glyphs */
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Campton ExtraBold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    src: local('Campton ExtraBold'), url('../fonts/campton/CamptonExtraBold.woff') format('woff');
    font-display: $font-display; /* Read next point */
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF; /* Download only latin glyphs */
}

//Writer
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Writer Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Writer Bold'), url('../fonts/writer/Writer-Bold.woff') format('woff');
    font-display: $font-display; /* Read next point */
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF; /* Download only latin glyphs */
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Writer Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Writer Regular'), url('../fonts/writer/Writer-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    font-display: $font-display; /* Read next point */
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF; /* Download only latin glyphs */
}

$font-family-primary: "Campton Bold", Tahoma, Verdana;
$font-family-primary-light: "Campton Medium", Tahoma, Verdana;
$font-family-primary-bold: "Campton ExtraBold", Tahoma, Verdana;

$font-family-secondary: "Writer Regular", Courier New, Consolas;
$font-family-secondary-bold: "Writer Bold", Courier New, Consolas;
```

It's a strange behaviour because it's not always happening.

[To reproduce it, the most certain way is to open the Default Mobile Explorer =>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vujx9.jpg)

This is how it's seen when font's are not showing(and the strange thing is that also is not swapping to the alternate font)
[Fonts not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3faMs.jpg)

This is how it should look
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXg2K.jpg)

I expect to have normal behaviour with this blazor app, and i'm not finding another guy with the same problem as me.

Comment: Is it that the FONT is not showing or the whole sections of the components are not showing?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Finally i found the problem, And the problem was the font itself. I don't know why but in mobile it was not showing.

I changed the font file (downloading from another source) and it started working.